# Is it possible to make a loading animation in a Console Application using C?

Tags: c, animation, console-application

I would like to know if it is possible to  make a loading animation in a Console Application that would always appear in the same line, like a flashing dot or a more complex ASCII animation.

Comment: Take a look at a few ascii characters like \b or \r

Comment: Possible: sure. But the real question is if it is desirable. 
Even simple progress indicating interferes with seeing what one types ahead from the shell. If you make the cursor move backwards, this becomes even far worse.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define INTERVAL (0.1 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)     // tenth second

int main(void) {

    int i = 0;
    clock_t target;
    char spin[] = "\\|/-";                  // '\' needs escape seq
    printf(" ");
    while(1) {
        printf("\b%c", spin[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        i = (i + 1) % 4;
        target = clock() + (clock_t)INTERVAL;
        while (clock() < target);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the `printf` calls lack a newline character, the output does not get flushed and this will not print anything for a while. Consider adding `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` before printing, which disables buffering of standard output. Or you could add a `fflush(stdout);` call on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

### One line

At first if you want to make animation only at one line, you could use `putchar('\b')` to remove last character and `putchar('\r')` to return to line beginning and then rewrite it.
Example:
    #include 
    #include

```
int main() {
    int num;
    while (1) {
        for (num = 1; num <= 3; num++) {
            putchar('.');
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf("\r   \r"); // or printf("\b\b\b");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But if you want to place it at specified line, you can clear and re-draw every frame, or use libs.

### Clearing method

You can do this with `system("clear")` or with `printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")`.
After that you'll need to re-draw your frame. I don't recommend this method.
But this is really unportable.

### Other libraries

You can use `ncurses.h` or `conio.h` depending on system type.

Ncurses example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    int row, col;

    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
    char loading[] = "-\\|/";
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            mvaddch(row/2, col/2, loading[i%4]);
            refresh();
            sleep(1);
            mvaddch(row/2, col/2, '\b');
        }
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The more portable way would be to use termcap/terminfo or (n)curses.

If you send ANSI escape sequences you assume the terminal to be capable of interpreting them (and if it isn't it'll result in a big mess.)

It's essentially a system that describes the capabilities of the terminal (if there's one connected at all).

In these days one tends to forget but the original tty didn't have a way to remove ink from the paper it typed the output on ...

Termcap tutorials are easy enough to find on Google. Just one in the GNU flavor here: https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html (old, but should still be good)

(n)curses is a library that will allow you control and build entire text based user interfaces if you want to.